# Typescript: how to derive argument type from other argument

Tags: typescript

I've got a function with two arguments that depend on each other. I would like to define something like if argument1.type equals something then argument2 is something else.

Here's an example code I was playing with

```js
enum TYPE {
    TYPE1 = "type1",
    TYPE2 = "type2",
};

type State1 = {
    property1: number,
};

type State2 = {
    property1: string,
    property2: string,
};

type Container1 = {
    type: TYPE.TYPE1,
};

type Container2 = {
    type: TYPE.TYPE2,
}

type Container = Container1 | Container2;

type State<C extends Container> = C extends Container1
  ? State1
  : C extends Container2
  ? State2
  : null

const fn = <C extends Container>(c: C, r: State<C>): State<C>["property1"] | null => {
    switch (c.type) {
        case TYPE.TYPE1: { 
            return r.property1;
        }
        case TYPE.TYPE2: {
            // When I'll use r.property2, typescript will complain
            return r.property1;
        }
        default: {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

// But here the `result` got correct type
const result = fn({type: TYPE.TYPE1}, {property1: 1});
```

Any help appreciated!
Thanks!